# How to logout Firebase user when signout method doesn't work on Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, logout

I've made an email authentication with Firebase but **even with a logout method it seems user isn't disconnected.**

The app should normally do this:

**LoginScreen > After clicking on "Connect with email" button, if user isn't connected show EmailAuthScreen or HomeScreen if user is connected > Logout inside NavDrawer**

The problem is when I go back to the LoginScreen after clicking on logout button in NavDrawer and click again on "Connect with Email" button it goes automatically to HomeScreen it means that the user is still connected.

I've seen it using:

```
print(user);
```

That show this:

```
D/FirebaseAuth(25175): Notifying id token listeners about user ( bzZKKDQT5DMDelvJ66EnRv9Ghlp6 ).
I/flutter (25175): User(displayName: , email: test@gmail.com, emailVerified: false, isAnonymous: false, metadata: UserMetadata(creationTime: 2022-06-15 04:04:36.071, lastSignInTime: 2022-06-15 23:45:38.713), phoneNumber: , photoURL: null, providerData, [UserInfo(displayName: , email: test@gmail.com, phoneNumber: , photoURL: null, providerId: password, uid: test@gmail.com)], refreshToken: , tenantId: null, uid: bzZKKDQT5DMDelvJ66EnRv9Ghlp6)
```

And I've used this in Main:

```
home: studentProvider.currentUser == null ? const LoginScreen() : const HomeScreen(),
```

**And with this in Main, clicking the logout button will result in a return to Home and not to LoginScreen.**

How can I solve this and really logout the user?

I've done this:

**Main**

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:g_conduite_student_test/provider/student_provider.dart';
import 'package:g_conduite_student_test/view/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:g_conduite_student_test/view/information_screen.dart';
import 'package:g_conduite_student_test/view/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'firebase_options.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    StudentProvider studentProvider = StudentProvider();

    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) {
        return studentProvider;
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: LoginScreen(),//studentProvider.currentUser == null ? const LoginScreen()
        //: const HomeScreen(),
        routes: {
          "/home": (context) => const HomeScreen(),
          "/information": (context) => const InformationScreen(),
        },//const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**StudentProvider**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class StudentProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User? currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
}
```

**LoginScreen**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import '../widget/sign_in_with_email_button.dart';
import '../widget/space_between_login_button.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String ROUTE_NAME = "/";

  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Image.asset(
              "assets/images/poker_token_blue.png",
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            SignInWithEmailButton(),
            SpaceBetweenLoginButton(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**SignInWithEmailButton**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../view/email_auth_screen.dart';

class SignInWithEmailButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignInWithEmailButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        _clickOnEmailButton(context);
      },
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        fixedSize: const Size(350, 45),
        primary: const Color(0xFFD0001C),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: const [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 30),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.email,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 30,

            ),
          ),
          Text(
            "Connect with email",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //----------------------------- Click on email button ------------------------------------------
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  void _clickOnEmailButton(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => EmailAuthScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**EmailAuthScreen**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterfire_ui/auth.dart';
import 'home_screen.dart';

class EmailAuthScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const EmailAuthScreen ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return SignInScreen(
              providerConfigs: [
                EmailProviderConfiguration(),
              ],
            );
          //return const LoginScreen();
          }
          return HomeScreen();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**NavDrawer**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:g_conduite_student_test/view/home_screen.dart';

import '../view/information_screen.dart';
import '../view/login_screen.dart';

class NavDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavDrawer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          DrawerHeader(
              child: Text(
                "My App",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                ],
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
              )
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text("Home"),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomeScreen.ROUTE_NAME);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.info),
            title: Text("My informations"),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, InformationScreen.ROUTE_NAME);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.power_settings_new),
            title: Text("Log out"),
            onTap: () {
              _logOut;
              _goToLoginScreen(context);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //----------------------------- Click on log out -----------------------------------------------
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Future<void> _logOut() async {
    // add something to set user == null
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      return;
    }
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //----------------------------- Go to login screen ---------------------------------------------
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  void _goToLoginScreen(BuildContext context){
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.ROUTE_NAME);
  }
}
```

Because it seems

```
Future<void> _logOut() async {
    // add something to set user == null
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      return;
    }
  }
```

Doesn't logout the user.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Solved the problem with this:

**Sign out is not an async method**

```
ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.power_settings_new),
        title: Text("Log out"),
        onTap: () {
          logOut()
          _goToLoginScreen(context);
        },
      ),

logOut() {
  FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your reasoning behind this? Because it **is** async. See the source for reference: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/firebase_auth.dart#L694